# iOS Pushkit framework for VOIP app with HTTP/2 APNS API

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, http2, pushkit

With the introduction of new HTTP/2 APNS interface, same certificate will work for background voip apps which would be identified using apns-topic under extension '( 1.2.840.113635.100.6.3.6 )'. That means if my app's bundle id is 'com.Sample.myApp', then I can use 'com.Sample.myApp.voip' to specify voip app.

Having said that, do I still need to implement Pushkit framework to make sure notification is directly delivered to my app to avoid any user intervention to accept the notification?

Also, as per my understanding server side (apns provider) implementation remain same with respect to delivering voip or regular push notifications using single certificate & same interface when talking to APNS using HTTP/2 API. Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong here.

Regards,
_Ayush

Answer (score 1):

You can use same bundle identifier, Just make sure provisioning profile must have selected with VOIP. else you would not get notification.

Yes, you need to implement Pushkit framework. if and if your app is related to VOIP. This helps specifically in silent push notification, that does not come in notification tray, but make active your app in background mode. ( would not invoke or come in foreground )

For example - If your app is like Skype.

Once you get incoming call notification, when you gets missed call notification, incoming call notification gets cancelled ( Removed from notification tray )

Getting silent push notification though push kit, you can schedule local notification, while getting another ( missed call ) notification you can remove earlier local notification and schedule missed call local notification.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Can you please also confirm if APNS SSL certificate with VOIP extension will work here. There is no context of Pushkit in Apple documentation when its talking about APNS. And when Apple talks about Pushkit, it said VOIP Services Certificate instead of APNS SSL certificate. Can we use VOIP Services certificate or APNS SSL Certificate with VOIP extension interchangeably?